# Find the leader from an Array

Tags: algorithm

A leader is a number that occurs MORE than HALF of the elements of an array. The Equi-leader will be defined if two consecutive section in the array has THAT leader (ie the leader occurs more than half of other elements in the `respective` section). As the section can vary, the array can have more than one Equi-leader. Say, I find the leader x of an array and now I would like to find the number of equi-leaders.

If a section and the consecutive section x occurs more than other elements (x > non_X for the segment), does it mean that in those 2 segments x occurred more than half of other elements as well? Remember, `x_Total > Array_Length/2`

A section is a subarray, say, take the element in the index of S. That creates 2 consecutive subarrays of [0,1,....., S] and [S+1, S+2, ..... N-1] and we need leaders both of the sections.

I know this is true, but, how to prove that? Not looking for code implementation.

Comment: The question is not clear. What is a section: a subarray, or a prefix, or a suffix, or half of the array, or something else? And what are consecutive sections?

Comment: @Gassa I updated the question with the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Still unsure whether I understand the question, but anyway.*

Let the length of the array be N.
Say the first part (subsection) has length L, and therefore the second one has length N-L.
Let C<sub>1</sub> be the number of values X in the first part, and C<sub>2</sub> be the number of values X in the second part.

By definition of an equi-leader (hopefully I got it right), we have C<sub>1</sub> > L / 2 and C<sub>2</sub> > (N-L) / 2.
Adding them together, we have C<sub>1</sub> + C<sub>2</sub> > N/2.

So, any equi-leader is also a leader for the whole array.
As there can be at most one leader, all equi-leaders are necessarily equal to this one leader.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to answer. However, the question is `C1 > Other elements (non x) in L/2` and  `C2 > Other elements (non x) in (N-L)/2`. Now can we say `C1 > L/2 and C2 > (N-L)/2`? We know the `total count of x > N/2` which makes it leader.  I accepted your answer anyway as I think no one will answer.

Comment: @Arefe Looks like yes, we can. Let the number of `X` in `L` first elements be `C`. So the number of other elements in `L` first elements is `L-C`. So we have `C > L-C`, which is the same as `2C > L`, or `C > L/2`.

Comment: @Arefe In words, "there are more X than non-X" is equivalent to "there are more than half X".

Comment: I knew this is true but was looking for simple math based provide like this. Thank you so much.